# About DB Synchronization

Tags: database, synchronization

I have a scenario mentioned below, for which i need an best possible approach 

1) I have 3 different DB lets say (Mysql, Sql & SqlLite)
2) Mysql resides in main server, Sql resides on middle ware server & SqlLite on client machine

3) Here mysql db holds all the master data

4) Sql has same copy of data which is present in Mysql(will be sync frequently)

5) This Sql data must sync back to users local machine i.e., into SqlLite

### Question

I need to know a best approach for synchronizing Mysql with Sql & then Sql to SqlLite(localDB)?
Few approaches which am aware of are

1) Writing a WCF service

2) Having a job kind of thing running on db which takes care of synchronization

Comment: Database synchronization is a complex topic, with many different approaches and not all experts agreeing on which is preferable. Your question asks not just for a single kind of DBMS being synchronized, but three quite different DBMS systems syncing amongst all of them. "Explain synchronization to me" is beyond the scope of this site--much less "explain multi-way, heterogenous sync." I can tell you, however, that it's MySQL, SQLite, and I presume the third one is Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan Eunice & Neil McGuigan for your replies <br/>D

Comment: Jonathan i would like to know the best approach/methodology for synchronizing the databases to keep it simple lets say we have 2 similar databases of type MSSQL one on Server and other on Local now i need to sync these frequently. So now i would like to know which approach would be better, having a WCF service running background which will sync both DB's at specific intervals or doing the same using a job running in one of the DB's or is there any best approach.